# How to use potentially malicious hardware safely

Tags: malware, hardware

I know the methods for running possible malicious programs safely but how do I keep my computer secure when I need to use a tool that might be malware. I cannot run it in a sandbox or virtual machine since it requires access to hardware level control.

Comment: If the *program* requires direct access control, then you need a lot of trust. The hardware and the data on the machine needs to be isolated in the event that the program is malicious.

Comment: The question is vague. What kind of hardware specifically ? USB HID device or something else ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't to be vague i am having to use a program to flash a phone but the program might be malicious ( Odin ) I am looking into finding a safe copy of the program but just trying to be safe

Comment: It's more or less like asking: how can I safely shoot myself in the head? Answer: use somebody else's head, or make a copy of your head and shoot that instead.

Comment: This is what i was thinking a live boot operating system like Ubuntu on a public WIFI network such as the library and a public computer and then copy the files to a USB afterwards take a clean install of Windows ( Program requires Windows ) without a internet connection and then flash the phone flash a new BIOS to the laptop and reinstall my original operating system

Comment: This way the executable can't be executed on the computer at the library since by default Linux can't execute a Windows executable and because since it's not on my network it can't be spread to any of my other devices and as long as the laptop has a fresh copy of Windows and no personal identifying information ( Windows doesn't even have to be activated ) And no internet connection because data is being transferred over the USB and since the network can't be connected to i don't have to worry about infecting rest of the network

Comment: And afterwards before i connect to a network i can flash a new copy of the BIOS and reinstall my everyday operating system i might be completely wrong about all of this but it was worth a ask

Comment: Note: I am aware you can install Ubuntu as a main or dual boot operating system but in this question i am using it as a live boot system